# Optimize php control stucture

Tags: php

I have the following issue. I tried to combine getting the UTM parameter and checking if the cookie was set in the same if, but it ended up in error.

`/index?utm_source=icework`

Here is are 4 if statements.

1. To check for a URL parameter and set a hidden form

   ```
   if (!isset($_GET['utm_source'])) {
     $UTM_Source = ""; 
   }
   ```
2. There is a function that set creates a cookie if the UTM is passed via the URL. The cookie name is adtrack_UTM_Source. If it does exist keep the field empty.

   ```
   if (!isset($_COOKIE['adtrack_UTM_Source'])) {
     $UTM_Source = "";
   }
   ```
3. If the utm source is passed, set the field value with the utm value

   ```
   if ( isset($_GET['utm_source'] ) ) {
     $UTM_Source = $_GET['utm_source'];
   }
   ```
4. If the cookie exists to set the value of the field again.

   ```
   if (isset($_COOKIE['adtrack_UTM_Source'])) {
     $UTM_Source = "icework";
   }
   ```

II. Hidden Form Field

```
<input type="hidden" id="atUTM_Source" name="atUTM_Source" value="<?php echo strtolower($UTM_Source) ?>"/>
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: what are you actually asking?

Comment: suggestion: use tenary operators to reduce everything to maximum 2 lines.

Comment: 4th is not logical. why hard code it to "icework"?

Comment: @Jeff Suggestion: Nesting ternaries results in unreadable, unmaintainable code unsuitable for use outside of code golf competitions.

Comment: Actually a way to populate 5 hidden fields with different utm parameters,  when the URL parameter are passed create 5 different cookie to keep the fields populated. Also the flexibility to pass only parameter or two without triggering an error. But most important reduce the amount of if statements.

Comment: The fourth can me made using the value of the cookie if it exists, I know, that was just the code I had at the moment, but you are right, no need to hard code it. If the cookie exists we need to keep the field value set

Comment: O forgot to mention. Sometimes the page is loaded without the parameters, that is why we need to check if the cookie exists and if it does, then populate the field.

Answer (score 1):

You can use ternary operator approach in your code. Simply:

```
$UTM_Source = (isset($_GET['utm_source'])) ? $_GET['utm_source'] : "";
$UTM_Source_Cookie = (isset($_COOKIE['adtrack_UTM_Source'])) ? "icework" : "";
```

Comment: I will give this a try. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you prefer the `$_COOKIE` source to the `$_GET` source, otherwise just swap the statements:

```
if( isset($_COOKIE['adtrack_UTM_Source']) ) {
    $UTM_Source = $_COOKIE['adtrack_UTM_Source'];
} else if( isset($_GET['utm_source']) ) {
    $UTM_Source = $_GET['utm_source']; 
} else {
    $UTM_Source = ''; // or whatever default you want
}
```

Comment: I will give this a try. Thank you.